# Writing results into a .txt file

Tags: python, arrays, text-files, with-statement, file-writing

I created a code to take two .txt files, compare them and export the results to another .txt file. Below is my code (sorry about the mess).

Any ideas? Or am I just an imbecile?

Using python 3.5.2:

```
# Barcodes Search (V3actual)

# Import the text files, putting them into arrays/lists

with open('Barcodes1000', 'r') as f:
    barcodes = {line.strip() for line in f}

with open('EANstaging1000', 'r') as f:
    EAN_staging = {line.strip() for line in f}

##diff = barcodes ^ EAN_staging 
##print (diff)



in_barcodes_but_not_in_EAN_staging = barcodes.difference(EAN_staging)

print (in_barcodes_but_not_in_EAN_staging)

# Exporting in_barcodes_but_not_in_EAN_staging to a .txt file

with open("BarcodesSearch29_06_16", "wt") as BarcodesSearch29_06_16:    # Create .txt file
    BarcodesSearch29_06_16.write(in_barcodes_but_not_in_EAN_staging)    # Write results to the .txt file
```

Comment: What is the specific problem?  What is the expected behavior?  You need to explain what's going on, not just say `Any ideas?`.

Comment: Are you hitting a particular error? - Also you can format your post in a code block. 4 spaces starting any line begins a codeblock

Comment: @Rick S Sorry about the vague question. The results are not appearing in the text file, like they should.

Comment: This is the problem.    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Glenn/jack/Barcodes_search_V3test.py", line 23, in <module>
    BarcodesSearch29_06_16.write(in_barcodes_but_not_in_EAN_staging)    # Write results to the .txt file
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `BarcodesSearch29_06_16.write(str(in_barcodes_but_not_in_EAN_staging))`. Also, you'll want to close the file after you're done writing to it with `BarcodesSearch29_06_16.close()`.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped!

Answer (score 2):

From the comments to your question, it sounds like your issue is that you want to save your list of strings as a file.  `File.write` expects a single string as input, while `File.writelines` expects a list of strings, which is what your data appears to be.

```py
with open("BarcodesSearch29_06_16", "wt") as BarcodesSearch29_06_16:
    BarcodesSearch29_06_16.writelines(in_barcodes_but_not_in_EAN_staging)
```

That will iterate through your list `in_barcodes_but_not_in_EAN_staging`, and write each element as a separate line in the file `BarcodesSearch29_06_16`.